# Aurelia Webpack datepicker is not a function

Tags: datepicker, aurelia

I have a custom attribute "datepicker" that complains of

```
TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
```

I am using skeleton-typescript-webpack as my starting point.

**datepicker.ts**

```js
import {inject, autoinject, customAttribute, DOM} from "aurelia-framework";
import moment from "moment";

import "jquery";
import "jquery-ui";

@customAttribute("datepicker")
@inject(DOM.Element)
export class JqueryUiDatePicker {
    constructor(private element: Element) {
    moment().format();
    }

    attached() {
        $(this.element)
            .datepicker({dateFormat: "DD/MM/YYYY"})
            .on("change", e => this.fireEvent((e.target) as Element, "input"));
    }

    detached() {
        $(this.element)
            .datepicker("destroy")
            .off("change");
    }

    private fireEvent(element: Element, name: string): void {
        const event = this.createEvent(name);
        this.element.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    private createEvent(name: string): Event {
        const event = document.createEvent("Event");
        event.initEvent(name, true, true);
        return event;
    }
}
```

**markup**

```
<input class="form-control" id="orderDate" datepicker placeholder="Order Date" type="text" value.bind="model.orderDate | dateFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY'">
```

It used to work when Aurelia was in beta, but after I've updated the my code with the latest skeleton-typescript-webpack, it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Try `import $ from 'jquery';`.

Here's blog for a related example: http://davismj.me/blog/semantic-custom-element/

Comment: I still got a similar error "Unhandled rejection TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).datepicker is not a function". In the beta webpack.config, I don't remember having to add jqueryui there to get it to work. For the Aurelia 1.0 webpack.config, I see there is a reference to config-global-jquery. Do I have to do something similar for jqueryui?

Answer (score 0):

I am using au cli (with typescript)... so YMMV; but the following import worked for me

```
 import * as $ from 'jquery'
```

yes, you do need to import jquery-ui as well